# Rails uploading to Vimeo API gives timeouts, while ARC doens't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vimeo, httparty

I'm testing a script that is using HTTParty to create uploads to Vimeo. The script worked a few weeks back, but now stopped working. Whenever I try to upload something I get `Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)` errors. The strange thing is, when I try exactly the same request using Advanced REST Client, it works perfectly.

So the method, endpoint, headers & body seem to be exactly the same, but somehow the request through HTTParty are giving the error I mentioned earlier.

Any ideas on how to debug this further? The last piece of code is just a simple HTTParty call:

```
call = HTTParty.public_send(put, 'endpoint from Vimeo ticket', 'header & body')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe they both have different default timeout values...

Comment: I'm testing this with a very small sample file, so I guess timeouts shouldn't really be in the equasion...